# Reading structures with typed slots in SBCL

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

Consider this simple code example:

```
(defstruct test
  (:example nil :type (simple-array single-float)))

(defparameter test-struct
  (make-test :example (make-array 10 :element-type 'single-float
                                     :initial-element 1.0)))
```

Nothing crazy here as we can see, a simple struct with a single slot is defined. We also specify that the `:example` slot is strongly type expected to be an array of single floats. No questions here, everything works fine.

Let us write the `test-struct` to a file now:

```
(with-open-file (out "~/Desktop/out.test"
             :direction :output
             :if-exists :supersede)
  (format out "~s" test-struct))
```

Again, no surprises, we get a nice little file on the desktop with the following contents:

```
#S(TEST :EXAMPLE #(1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0))
```

Tension is starting to creep in, however, as we notice that nothing is suggesting that this particular literal array is supposed to contain single floats. With this suspicion, let us try loading this struct back:

```
(defparameter loaded-struct
  (with-open-file (in "~/Desktop/out.test")
    (read in nil)))
```

And here we are, SBCL happily drops us into a debugger:

[image: SBCL drops into a debugger when attempting to read a typed array]

The question is: is there a way to instruct SBCL to verify that this array slot in the structure is of a valid type and load it? Or in other words, is it possible to read structs with strongly typed slots back without resorting to building custom writers and constructors?

Comment: Just tried loading the struct in LispWorks and it worked fine, however I would not trust LispWorks's treatment of single floats, for all I know it only can handle those in a boxed form so it probably does not care about the declaration altogether.

Comment: Note that the default value is set to NIL, which is not an array.

Comment: @RainerJoswig the slot is actually not supposed to be empty so it does not matter really, in fact it can be helpful as sbcl will raise a flag if no value has been supplied when trying to assign nil to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you print the object *readably*:

```
(equalp test-struct
        (read-from-string 
          (with-output-to-string (o)
            (write test-struct :readably t :stream o))))
=> T ;; no error while reading the structure back
```

The string is:

```
"#S(TEST
   :EXAMPLE #.(COERCE #(1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0)
                      '(SIMPLE-ARRAY SINGLE-FLOAT (*))))"
```

If you want to use `format`, use `~W` while `*print-readably*` is T.